# How to tell TypeScript that an error from a `try catch` statement is an object that contains a specific property without using the `any` type?

Tags: typescript, types, try-catch

I get an error in the `console.log` statement below:

```
try {
    // ...
} catch(e) {
    if (typeof e === "object" && e !== null && e.hasOwnProperty("data")) {
        console.log(e.data);
    }
}
```

when I try to access `e.data`, I get the following TypeScript error:

`Property 'data' does not exist on type 'object'.ts(2339)`

I explicitly check if `e` has a property of `data` though right? So I'm not understanding why TypeScript is saying `data` doesn't exist on e.

How can I tell TypeScript properly that e has a property of data?
I know I can cast the error as an `any` type, but I don't think this is good practice and would like to refrain from using `any` if possible. My work does not allow for casting `any` anywhere in the codebase.

screenshots of my errors below:

[e is of unknown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aOQTv.png)

[typescript error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cGDa9.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [predicate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=11&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4JwngBA3gsAUBRED0yIDpPwL4QMYCGweAFhABQCmAlNPEhAJYBmFJBAzgCJEFXW1YCBkjwB7AHYcxAG0roZYgOZV0AE17UA3PSTYc8eMwCuEvMEaSI7br3JiARgCtK5gFwRTAawliA7hLUHo4u5kwc0BAawAQe3r4BELhCDCCUwMYgEhTAYAAOlGKsIa7AEAC8lRAARCXm1RAAZI0QdcAA-Og2APIBAAogYgUgueTV0QTVAhDt7RDMBDIclDhAA) !

```
try {
    // ...
} catch (e) {
    if (hasData(e)) {
        console.log(e.data);
    }
}

function hasData(object: unknown): object is { data: unknown } {
    return (typeof object === "object" && object?.hasOwnProperty("data")) ?? false
}
```

[Playground][2]

Comment: Thank you, but I believe this would be the same as if I just casted `e` as the `any` type. I want to refrain from using `any` if possible. Do you know how to do this without using `any`?

Comment: No, this is not a cast. The pridicate describes what the function is doing, here checking whether data is a member of your object !  

Of course YMMV on the typing of `object:any`

Comment: And yes you can replace `any` by `unknown`  !

Comment: Ok great thank you! I was able to make it work with:
`
function hasData(e: unknown): e is { data: any } {
  return typeof e === "object" && e !== null && e.hasOwnProperty("data")
}
`

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways you could fix this, depending what you're going for.

But this is the simplest:

```
try {
    // ...
} catch(e: any) {
    if (typeof e === "object" && e !== null && e.data) {
        console.log(e.data);
    }
}
```

Note that TypeScript has limitations surrounding what you can do in terms of type specification in a `catch` clause, so you can't do something more complicated like declare an error type containing a `data` property or anything.

Here's the above code in a [TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4JwngBA3gUB8QPSIgOnTAvhAxgQ2BwAsAKAUwC4I8A7MASmjgQEsAzCE4MABzIHsOZCAF4xEAET8ARgCsyOYBIgAyFRGEBCcTQCuAG32r1ZVABMCeRrAS3c-GgGd++0-v4Bzcucv0A3MzwmFhAA).

Comment: I still get the same error, this time the error is in 2 spots though, the original spot, and inside the if statement as well. `... && e.data` causes the same error.

Comment: Can you post the appropriate code? As you can see in the playground I posted, the error does not occur there.

Comment: You added the `any` cast or I missed it. With the `any` cast, it works now.

Comment: excellent! glad you're on your way.

Comment: @MadisonReibel I'd strongly recommend against the use of `any` under all circumstances, it effectively defeats the purpose of using TypeScript because it disables type checking. If, like in this case, there isn't any great way of achieving what you want in TS, use a type guard (like in the other answer) or use `as` to assert the type - which isn't great, but better than `any` at least